# Programmatically set TextBlock Foreground Color

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, colors, textblock

Is there a way to do this in Windows Phone 7?

I can reference the TextBlock in my C# Code, but I don't know exactly how to then set the foreground color of it.

```
myTextBlock.Foreground = 
//not a clue...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 153, accepted):

```
 textBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
```

Answer (score 64):

Foreground needs a Brush, so you can use

```
textBlock.Foreground = Brushes.Navy;
```

If you want to use the color from **RGB** or **ARGB** then

```
textBlock.Foreground = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Color.FromArgb(100, 255, 125, 35));
```

or

```
textBlock.Foreground = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(Colors.Navy);
```

To get the Color from **Hex**

```
textBlock.Foreground = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFDFD991"));
```

Comment: Indian Programmer - Thank you! Tell me, what namespace should one use to use the Brushes class?

Comment: In the last example also you need System.Windows.Media.Colors.Navy in parenthesis, like
TextBlock.Foreground = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(System.Windows.Media.Colors.Red); 
, that is of course if you have not referenced the namespace in the beginning of the file

Comment: Is there any "FromHex()" available?

Comment: Trying to use the HEX example.  Getting Error CS0120 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TypeConverter.ConvertFromString(string)'

Comment: Great, thanks for also showing how to use hex values too!!

Answer (score 14):

You could use [`Brushes.White`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brushes.white.aspx) to set the foreground.

```
myTextBlock.Foreground = Brushes.White;
```

The [`Brushes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.brushes.aspx) class is located in [`System.Windows.Media`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.aspx) namespace.

Or, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> while the cursor is on the unknown class name to automatically add `using` directive.

Comment: Thanks! What namespace should one use to get access to the Brushes class? Can't seem to find it..

Answer (score 11):

To get the Color from Hex.

```
using System.Windows.Media;

Color color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FFDFD991");
```

and then set the foreground

```
textBlock.Foreground = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(color);
```

Comment: A variation of this can also be used to check the color which is useful.  +1:                                                    if ((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(wpfComponent.Foreground.ToString()) == Colors.Red) { ...