# Change foreground text of texbox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I am creating a Windows store application in C# and XAML (not WPF) using Visual stuio 2013 Professional edition.

I already have an if statement so the program will be able to perform this function

```
if (TextBoxForRainbow.Text=="rainbow" || TextBoxForRainbow.Text=="Rainbow")
{
    RainbowButton.Opacity = 100;
}
```

I have explored methods such as:
TextBoxForRainbow.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(color: "red"); but to no avail
The link I found talking about this method is here [Programmatically set TextBlock Foreground Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12727491/programmatically-set-textblock-foreground-color)

Is there a specific namespace or reference that I need to insert to fulfill this function?

What I want is when the user enters the correct text in the texbox, which in this case is 'rainbow' i would like the text to change to a green colour.

Comment: Are you building a Windows Store App?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Yes a windows store app :)

Comment: You should be more specific about which platform you're developing in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you mentioned that you tried

```
TextBoxForRainbow.Foreground new SolidColorBrush(color: "red");
```

That won't work, the constructor of the `SolidColorBrush` expects a `Color`, not a string.

Here's my reworked example:

**XAML**

```
<StackPanel Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
  <TextBox x:Name='TextBoxForRainbow'
            TextChanged='TextBoxForRainbow_TextChanged'
            Text='Demo' />
</StackPanel>
```

**Code**

```
private void TextBoxForRainbow_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
  if (String.Equals(TextBoxForRainbow.Text, 
                    "rainbow",
                     StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
  {
    TextBoxForRainbow.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Green);
  }
}
```

[image: Screenshot]